# Opencart: Pass quantity variable to success.php

Tags: variables, opencart

I have asked this question in the Opencart forums but have yet to receive any responses, so i thought i might ask the experts here @stackoverflow :)

I am trying to see exactly how i can pass the 'quantity' of the items ordered to the success.php page so i can then pass that to another php script that will generate an array based on the quantity.

This is my goal:

- Customer Buys 5 items
- Customer checks out and processes CC through Paypal Pro
- Paypay returns a successful transaction
- Now i want the success.php page to pass a variable($quantity) to
  myNewScript.php page
- myNewScript.php page will generate some random strings and then i
  want to attach these random strings to the confirmation email that
  opencart generates and sends to the customer.

Where should i start.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in checkout/success controller. Get the $quantity and use redirect function to redirect to your custom page:

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/myNewScript','quantity='.$quantity));
```

Comment: Do you know how i would get the quantity out of the success.php page? Also im not wanting to actually redirect the cart to another page i just want to run the myNewScript.php page silently in the success.php page.